# How to serialize embedded associations in ember data?

Tags: ember.js

## Background

Recently [Tom Dale announced](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/428#issuecomment-10977905) that "Embedded loading is now back!".  However it only appears to be fully supported for the *loading* scenario.  It is unclear if *serializing* embedded associations is still under development, or if users are expected to implement it themselves by building a custom serializer.

## Requirements

The JSON for my embedded association looks like this:

```
{
  inputs: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Favorite Color",
      type: "SelectInput",
      options: {
        choices: [ 'red', 'green', 'yellow' ]
      }
    },   
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "email",
      type: "TextInput",
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe the "ember way" to represent this is to build a custom serializer that will convert my JSON to models like:

```
App.Choice = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  input: DS.belongsTo( 'App.Input' )
});

App.Input = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  type: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  choices: DS.hasMany( 'App.Choice' )
});
```

## Attempted Solution

The following solution mostly works, however it feels like I must be "doing it wrong" because I'm having to reverse engineer and subclass so much code.

```
Customizer.MyRESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  dirtyRecordsForAttributeChange: function(dirtySet, record, attributeName, newValue, oldValue) {
    if(record.constructor === Customizer.Choice) {
      if(newValue === oldValue) { return; }

      var input = null;
      if (attributeName == 'name') {
        input = record.get('input');
      }
      else if(attributeName == 'input') {
        input = newValue;
      }
      if( input ) {
        dirtySet.add( input );
      }
    }
    else {
      this._super(dirtySet, record, attributeName, newValue, oldValue);
    }
  },

  dirtyRecordsForBelongsToChange: function(dirtySet, child, relationship) {
    if(child.constructor === Customizer.Choice) {
      var input = child.get( 'input' );
      if( input ) {
        dirtySet.add( input );
      }
    }
    else {
      this._super(dirtySet, child, relationship);
    }
  },

  dirtyRecordsForHasManyChange: function(dirtySet, parent, relationship) {
    this._super(dirtySet, parent, relationship);
  }
});

Customizer.MyRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.mappings.set( 'Customizer.Input', { choices: { embedded: 'load' } } );
  },

  extractEmbeddedHasMany: function(type, hash, key) {
    if(type == Customizer.Input) {
      if(!(hash['options'] && hash['options']['choices'])) { return null; }

      var choices = [];
      hash['options']['choices'].forEach(function(choice, i){
        var choiceId = hash['id'] + '_' + i;
        var inputId = hash['id'];
        choices[i] = { id: choiceId, input_id: inputId, name: choice };
      });
      return choices;
    }

    return this._super(type, hash, key);
  },

  addHasMany: function(data, record, key, relationship) {
    this._super(data, record, key, relationship);

    if( key === 'choices' ) {
      var choices = record.get('choices').map(function( choice ){
        return choice.get( 'name' );
      });
      data['options'] = data['options'] || {};
      data['options']['choices'] = choices;
    }
  }

});

Customizer.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 10,
  adapter: Customizer.MyRESTAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'api/v1',
    bulkCommit: false,
    serializer: Customizer.MyRESTSerializer
  })
})
```

## Request For Feedback

- Is this the right path?
- Is the ember team actively working on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the embedded-records branch of ember-data:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/commits/embedded-records

In particular, see this commit for saving embedded data:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/0abd3b965c50dfeb23bd8ff50751825482050e68

Full support for embedded records is right around the corner :)

**Update**

Embedded records branch was merged into master on 12/28/2012:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/b5d7c478e79aa9706e0196b8769b7ef67bb26fc4

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a variation of http://mozmonkey.com/2013/12/serializing-embedded-relationships-ember-data-beta/. In my case, I add the `id` to the JSON, or if it's not dirty, I just send the `id` by itself.

```
class App.ApplicationSerializer extends DS.ActiveModelSerializer
  # Based on http://mozmonkey.com/2013/12/serializing-embedded-relationships-ember-data-beta/
  # Also see http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-beta-3-and-saving-hasmany-relationships-with-activemodelserializer`-and-rails/3167
  serializeHasMany: (record, json, relationship) ->
    key = relationship.key
    hasManyRecords = Ember.get(record, key)
    embed = relationship.options.embed
    if embed && hasManyRecords
      json[key] = []
      hasManyRecords.forEach (item, index) =>
        json[key].push @serializeItem(item, embed)
    else
      @._super(record, json, relationship)

  serializeBelongsTo: (record, json, relationship) ->
    key = relationship.key
    belongsToRecord = Ember.get(record, key)
    embed = relationship.options.embed
    if embed
      json[key] = @serializeItem(belongsToRecord, embed)
    else
      @._super(record, json, relationship)

  serializeItem: (item, embed) ->
    if embed == 'ifDirty'
      if item.isDirty
        data = item.serialize()
      else
        data = {}
      data['id'] = item.id
    else if embed == 'always'
      data = item.serialize()
      data['id'] = item.id
    else
      null
    data
```